# Approximate Optimization by Finitely Supported Measures

Tags: measure-theory, optimization

Let $X$ be a compact space and $A$ be a compact (in the weak* sense) set of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$. Say that there is a measure $\mu$ over $X$ (and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) such that
$$ a \in argmax_A \int_X a(x) \mu(\text{d}x)$$

My question is: does there exist a **finitely supported** $\hat\mu$ such that

$$ a \in argmax_A \int_X a(x) \hat\mu(\text{d}x)$$

In other words, if $a$ is the maximizer of the expectation given some arbitrary measure is it also the maximizer of a finite measure?

Comment: The set of finitely supported measures is dense in the set of all measures on a compact space, so you could arbitrarily finely approximate $\mu$ by $\hat{\mu}$, then let $\hat{\mu}$ converge weakly to $\mu$ (i.e., convergence in distribution or the prohorov metric). You can then get the error by using the argmax of $\mu$ and not $\hat{\mu}$ as small as you want. Is that enough?

Comment: No. I understand that if $a$ is the unique maximize, this is true. The question is weather this still holds when we need weak inequalities.